# Visual Web Developer Document Formatting is not working

Tags: visual-web-developer

When I am trying to format the document with CTRL+K,CTRL+D it says **The Operation could not be completed. The parameter is incorrect.**

How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. Some elements was causing the problem. To determine which one is the problem,you can use CTRL+K,CTRL+F to contract the possibilities and you are there.